# Locating install printer PPD driver url script

Tags: printing, driver

Is it possible to output the PPD driver path my installed printer is using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get information about the installed printer driver with `system_profiler`:

```
pse@Mithos:~$ system_profiler SPPrintersSoftwareDataType
Printer Software:

    PPDs:

      PPDs:
          Path: /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/CanonIJMG7100series.ppd.gz
          Version: 11.7.1.0
          Path: /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/CanonIJMP520series.ppd.gz
          Version: 10.84.2.0
          Path: /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/CanonIJMP540series.ppd.gz
          Version: 10.84.2.0
...
```